# What's the IP being connected by windows remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Our team uses the same account 'administrator' to work on same Windows 7 remote desktop.

If I get the machine, if another person remotely connects to the machine my connection is interrupted.

Is it possible to know who is interrupting my connection by his/her IP address?

Comment: Something's wrong if multiple people are trying to use the same Windows workstation via Remote Desktop at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the time and when you reconnect to the machine, you can see the connection log when you open Computer Management (right click on "Computer" under start menu or desktop, if enabled there) and select:
- Event Viewer
-- Applications and Service Logs
--- Microsoft
---- Windows
----- TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager
------ Operational

In the "General" -tab there should be a row with "Source Network Address".

Comment: So, I can not get information about who interrupt me except I reconnect to the server?
If I re-connect to the server, My coworker will be interrupted by me again.

Comment: @DanielYCLin Actually, you can connect to the remote machine's event log if you run Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe) in the context of the "Administrator" account AND this account has the same password as that of the "Administrator" on the remote machine. (Also, Firewall mustn't be blocking it.)

Comment: Yes, like Fleet Command said, remote viewing is possible - even with your local Event Viewer. Although it requires that "Remote Event Log Management" -exception is enabled in the firewall and that you have sufficient rights on the target machine with your current account.

Comment: Unfortunately, for security reason, my local machine's administrator's password set as different with the remote machine. So, It seems I can not remote get the login information except I've setup another machine with the same password.